# Zyxel NR5101 - WAN direction?

Tags: router, wan

I'm looking at [Zyxel NR5101 product specifications](https://www.zyxel.com/global/en/products/mobile-broadband/5g-nr-indoor-router-nr5101/specifications) where it says:

> Two 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet RJ-45 LAN ports, LAN1 can be configured for Ethernet WAN port

I'm used to having Asus routers where I would insert the RJ-45 cable that came from the ISP into my apartment into the blue WAN port with a globe above it. The router would leech the Internet from that cable and broadcast it over Wi-Fi.

I want to find out whether it'll work with that Zyxel NR5101. Because while I understand it is primarily a 4G/5G model, I want to know whether I have this backup option if I ever need to use the cable internet.

My confusion is: when they say *LAN1 can be configured for Ethernet WAN port*, does it mean:

1. **WAN-in**, so the port will receive incoming signal from an external cable provider (which is what I want), or
2. **WAN-out**, so the port will send the signal NR5101 receives from mobile data out via an RJ-45 cable, so that on the other end I can connect any other router or infrastructure to broadcast it further; so essentially NR5101 acts as an ISP of sorts
3. **Both**?

Please help me figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: "*My confusion is: ... does it mean: ...*" - Only #1. The 4G/5G radio section would be disabled, and then you can use this box as just a plain router, possibly with a (cable or xDSL) modem from a different ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most consumer devices the WAN port is the "uplink" port.

Also note that "cable" internet may mean something different to you. In the US "cable" means internet that is served by a "cable tv/internet" provider over coaxial cables, and you use a modem whose "WAN" port is actually a coaxial connector, and the "LAN" ports of this modem are RJ45, to which you connect your devices, or, if you're running your own routers following the modem, you will connect these router's WAN ports to the LAN port(s) on the modem.

Your experience with an ISP that serves internet directly to you over RJ45 indicates that you were getting "internet over ethernet", or your ISP just hid where their non-RJ54 service feeds came into the actual modem.

This device can connect to upstream network sources and whatever services that are offered over them (internet from a modem, for instance).

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry for the confusion, you're right, I didn't mean *cable* in the US sense.